# Flutter- Getting and error when asking for Nearbyplaces

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-nearby

Hi I want to implement Google Map and nearby Search in Flutter and I almost did it but I don't understand the error that I'm getting while trying to fetch the places near my position.

I searched online but I couldn't figure it out, can anyone tell me what is wrong please. I lost almost 2h searching the web for the fix but nothing.

This is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_place/google_place.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  var googlePlace = GooglePlace("");
  //this are the longitude and the latitude of the phone
  double lng;
  double lat;


  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    getPosition().then((value) => getLocationNearBy());
  }

  Future<Position> getPosition() async {
    LocationPermission permission = await checkPermission();
    LocationPermission permission2 = await requestPermission();
    Position position =
        await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    lat = position.latitude;
    lng = position.longitude;
    print(position);
    return position;
  }

  void getLocationNearBy() async {
    var result = await googlePlace.search
        .getNearBySearch(Location(lat: lat, lng: lng), 2000, type: "bars");
    print(result);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error:

```
 Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module 

com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:6
I/DynamiteModule(18683): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 6
I/DynamiteLoaderV2Impl(18683): [71] Googlecertificates
W/m.example.ipil(18683): ClassLoaderContext type mismatch. expected=PCL, found=DLC (PCL[] | DLC[];PCL[/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk*4144957280:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex*3286414090:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes3.dex*660981783:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes4.dex*371746816:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes5.dex*1029310577:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes6.dex*1730292004:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes7.dex*2560797352:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes8.dex*1790620740:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes9.dex*2957673897:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes10.dex*1136895787:/data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes11.dex*1461101890:/data/app/com
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Found duplicate classes, falling back to extracting from APK : /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d4/GoogleCertificates.apk
W/m.example.ipil(18683): NOTE: This wastes RAM and hurts startup performance.
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Found duplicated class when checking oat files: 'Landroidx/annotation/Keep;' in /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d4/GoogleCertificates.apk and /data/app/com.example.ipill-sEbMOSkwYUXtrKfO0SfLPQ==/base.apk!classes13.dex
W/m.example.ipil(18683): 
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/m.example.ipil(18683): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 83801(6328KB) AllocSpace objects, 143(8420KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 7253KB/14MB, paused 211us total 141.179ms
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  (18683): uid=10378(com.example.ipill) GoogleApiHandle identical 3 lines
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  (18683): uid=10378(com.example.ipill) GoogleApiHandle identical 2 lines
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  (18683): uid=10378(com.example.ipill) GoogleApiHandle identical 1 line
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  (18683): uid=10378(com.example.ipill) GoogleApiHandle identical 5 lines
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/m.example.ipil(18683): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  (18683): uid=10378(com.example.ipill) GoogleApiHandle identical 4 lines
```

Comment: Can you confirm if you are passing an API key here "var googlePlace = GooglePlace("")"?

Comment: Yes I can confirm it for sure.

Comment: I see. Is your API key restricted? If so, try unrestricting it and see if the issue is still there. Also, make sure that Places API and billing is enabled on your project.

Comment: Yeah I did all of that but nothing. Eventually I found the solution. I had to remove the .location package in the pubspec.yaml

Comment: Good to know you've found the solution. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem make sure you don't have the package location in your pubspec.yaml and at the same time, google.services.gms.